# What is the expected time at which a success $S$ followed by a failure $F$, occurs for the first time in a sequence of Bernoulli trials?

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, conditional-expectation, bernoulli-distribution

We have $P(S) = a$ and $P(F) = 1-a$.

I want to find the expected time at which $SF$ occurs for the first time. I'm following a method given in my lectures but not getting the right answer so I must be misunderstanding. This is my attempt:

Let $T_i$ be the number of further trials needed until $SF$ occurs for the first time.

Note that due to the "fresh start property" we have E[$T_i$] = E[$T_j$] $\forall i,j \in \{1, 2,...\}$.

We define a new random variable, $V$, with
$$
V =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if trial starts with SF} \\
2, & \text{if trial starts with SS} \\
3, & \text{if trial starts with F}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, our aim is to compute $\mathbb{E}[T_1]$. So,

If $V=1 \implies T_1 = 2$

If $V=2 \implies T_1 = 2 + T_3 = 2 + T_1$

If $V=3 \implies T_1 = 1 + T_2 = 1 + T_1$

So, we have
$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[T_1] 
&= \mathbb{E}_V[E_T[T_1 | V]] \\[2ex]
&= \mathbb{E}[T_1|V=1]Pr(V=1) + \mathbb{E}[T_1|V=2]Pr(V=2) + \mathbb{E}[T_1|V=3]Pr(V=3) \\[2ex]
&= 2a(1-a) + a^2E[2+T_1] + (1-a)\mathbb{E}[T_1] \\[2ex]
&= a + 1 + \mathbb{E}[T_1](a^2 - a +1) \\[2ex]
\implies \mathbb{E}[T_1] &= \frac{-a-1}{a^2-a}
\end{align}$

But this is apparently incorrect, I'm trying my best to follow the method shown to me in lecture to calculate the same thing but for $SS$ instead of $SF$. What am I doing wrong/misunderstanding?

---

EDIT:

I think through the below comments I've understood that I'm doing something wrong when dealing with the case of $S$ happening. So, if we redefine $V$ as:

$$
V =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if trial starts with SF} \\
2, & \text{if trial starts with S} \\
3, & \text{if trial starts with F}
\end{cases}
$$

Because starting with $SS$ and starting with $S$ is the same (fresh start). But, I still can't get the right answer. I'm confident that

If $V=1 \implies T_1 = 2 \implies \mathbb{E}[T_1|V=1] = 2$

If $V=3 \implies T_1 = 1 + T_2 = 1 + T_1 \implies \mathbb{E}[T_1|V=3] = \mathbb{E}[1+T_1]$

But I'm stumped when it comes to $\mathbb{E}[T_1|V=2]$

Comment: The "fresh start" property (whatever it may exactly be) sounds not applicable, because if you start with some failures, and then get a success, you are suddenly nearer to what you want! In other words, after an SS start, you are not "back at square 1" (you need at least 2 trials to end your experiment from the starting position, but if the next trial is a failure after SS, your are done).

Comment: @lngix AH! Of course! I'll try again with that understanding, thank you!

Comment: @lngix So, I've tried again but still gotten the wrong answer. I interpreted your comment to mean I should take $E[T_1|V=2] = E[T_1 - 1]$ as we already have an S, so the expected number of trials until SF occurs would be one less than what we would expect from a "fresh start". I got a final answer of $E[T_1] = \frac{3a^2-a-1}{a^2-a}$, but this is again wrong..

Comment: One way is to define different states based on how "far" you are currently towards the goal. So state 1 would be if you "haven't started" yet (at the beginning and if the previous trial was a failure that didn't end the sequence), state 2 if the previous trial was a success and state 3 if the previous 2 were success and failure (so you are done when you reach state 3.

For each state you can describe to which state you move with certain outcomes. For example if in state 1 you have next a success, you move to state 2. If you have a failure, you stay in state 1. Same for the other states.

Comment: @ingx But then what is $E[T_1|V=2]$? Would it be $E[T_1 - 1]$ as I thought before for SS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define a random variable (V) to describe the starting point of the trial as follows:
$$
V = 
\begin{cases} 
1, & \text{if the trial starts at } S, \\
2, & \text{if the trial starts at } F. 
\end{cases}
$$

Our goal is to calculate $E[T_1]$, the expected number of trials. By the law of total expectation, we know:
$$
E[T_1] = E[E[T_1|V]] = E[T_1|V=1]P(V=1) + E[T_1|V=2]P(V=2).
$$

Now, we consider the expectations $E[T_1|V=1]$ and $E[T_1|V=2]$ separately:

1. For $E[T_1|V=1]$, we are dealing with the expected time until the first failure, given the first trial was a success. This follows a geometric distribution, thus:
   $$
   E[T_1|V=1] = E[Geom(1-a)] + 1 = \frac{1}{1-a} + 1,
   $$
   where the "+1" accounts for the initial success.
2. For $E[T_1|V=2]$, it is simply the expected time for achieving "SF" plus the one failed trial, hence:
   $$
   E[T_1|V=2] = 1 + E[T_1].
   $$

Applying the law of total expectation, we combine these to form:
$$
E[T_1] = \left( \frac{1}{1-a} + 1 \right) \cdot a + (1 + E[T_1]) \cdot (1-a).
$$

Solving this equation simplifies down to the expression:
$$
E[T_1] = \frac{1}{a \cdot (1-a)}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $N$ is first occurrence of SF, then $N=N_1+N_2$ where $N_1\sim\mathsf{Geo}(1-a)$ and $N_2\sim\mathsf{Geo}(a)$. We compute the distribution of $N$ by the law of total probability:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(N=n) &= \mathbb P(N_1+N_2=n)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\mathbb P(N_1+N_2=n\mid N_2=k)\mathbb P(N_2=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\mathbb P(N_1=n-k)\mathbb P(N_2=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a^{n-k-1}(1-a)\cdot(1-a)^{k-1}a\\
&= a^n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1-a}a\right)^k.
\end{align}
If $a=\frac12$ then the above reduces to $(n-1)2^{-n}$, so the expectation is
$$
\mathbb E[N] = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \mathbb n\cdot P(N=n) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)2^{-n} = 4.
$$
Else, we evaluate the geometric sum
$$
\mathbb P(N=n) = \frac{(1 - a)^n a - (1 - a) a^n}{1-2a}
$$
and compute
$$
\mathbb E[N] = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n\cdot \mathbb P(N=n)
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty n\cdot \frac{(1 - a)^n a - (1 - a) a^n}{1-2a}
= \frac1{a(1-a)}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for this! Could you explain or point me to some resource that explains this method? We've not been shown this in my course and the method I was trying to use before is all I have been shown for calculation this sort of thing!

Comment: The time until absorption in a Markov chain has a discrete phase-type distribution, and there are various more general ways to compute the expectation. For this problem, though, I simply observed that a success followed by a failure consists of some number of failures (possibly zero) followed by a success, then some number of successes (possibly zero) followed by a failure. The geometric distribution naturally comes to mind.